# Can't connect to memcached from PHP

Tags: php, apache, memcached

CentOS version 6.8.
All things installed from yum.
php version 5.6.
memcached service installed and running.
also installed php-memcached module (not memcache).

When i try run this code from bash - it works well. When I try run it trough apache as a php page - it even not connect to the memcached server and not return any errors.

Code:

```
<?php
   $m = new Memcached();
   $m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

   $m->set('test_key','test_value');

   print_r($m->get('test_key'));
?>
```

Memcached server is running in verbose mode (memcached -vv -m64 -l127.0.0.1). When I execute the code above from console, memcached server log is:

```
<28 new auto-negotiating client connection<br>
28: Client using the ascii protocol<br>
<28 set test_key 0 0 10<br><br>
>28 STORED<br>
<28 get test_key<br>
>28 sending key test_key<br>
>28 END<br>
<28 quit<br>
<28 connection closed.<br>
```

When I run it as trough apache - no any log messages in verbose console at all.

Comment: what can be seen in the php error log?

Comment: No any messages in apache log, and also no any messages in php log if I set up error_log file in php. A page code works without any errors, notices and alerts.

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was with SELinux configuration. It need to set up to on httpd_can_network_memcache variable using command:

       > setsebool httpd_can_network_memcache 1